# Hide tools in 3D viewport on Blender 2.8

Tags: 3d-view

I was wondering if there is a way to turn off these four tools on the 3D viewport:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Yes, just like that. Unfortunately it also hide the new axis thingy next to it, which I like a lot.

Comment: thanks, I don't use the axis thingy so I'm good. Thank you!